# drawable xml(android)

Tags: android, android-drawable

Как программно задать изображение на кнопке при клике на неё?

> android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_plus_1"

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/expandableButton1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_spravka"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_plus_1"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Справочник"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp" />
```

P.S.

```
setCompoundDrawables();
```

Не помогает

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно либо вызывать метод `setBounds` у drawable перед установкой либо сразу использовать [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 2):

```
<ImageButton android:src="@drawable/image_btn_src" ... />
```

Создаёте хмл типо `image_btn_src.xml` которая содержит :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_pressed"/>
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/icon_unpressed"/>
</selector>
```

В ХМЛ файле есть состояния кнопки  можеет для любого задать фон ,фотку или еще чтото что душе угодно

Answer (score 1):

Пример как применять для фона кнопки изображение из `Drawable` по клику:

```
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.expandableButton1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    btn.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_plus_1));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `LinearLayout` с `ImageView` вместо кнопки и вместо `background` для `ImageView` задавать через `SRC`. При клике по `LinearLayout` потом можешь задать другую картинку с помощью метода `setBackgroundResource()`