# Как изменить программно solid color в файле drawable/backborder.xml?

Tags: android, kotlin

Нужно изменить цвет в строке xml-файла, описывающего background (задается через свойство background) `<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />` на другой. Как эту операцию сделать программно? Чтобы не пришлось подменять весь xml-файл. При кажущейся простоте вопроса ответ на сайте не нашел. Можно вроде как до строки в ресурсе добраться...

```xml
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/layer_id"
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="@color/border_dark_grey" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Вот здесь вроде как рассматривался этот вопрос, но пока не понял:

[drawable xml(android)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/600569/drawable-xmlandroid)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772537/i-need-to-change-the-stroke-color-to-a-user-defined-color-nothing-to-do-with-th

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13585496/change-shape-border-color-at-runtime

Comment: Цвет чего хотите менять? Отредактируйте вопрос, приведите пример вашей xml. И пример того, как вы ее используете.

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: Как вы этот drawable используете? Приложите детали в вопрос. В какую вью встраиваете, в xml или в коде?

Comment: Опишите подробнее, какую проблему хотите решить, вы не хотите дублировать xml с разными цветами? Цвета будут фиксированные? Либо нужна максимальная гибкость и динамика в коде?

Comment: Этот xml использую в android studio как фон текстового поля. По сути он рисует линию снизу. Надо менять цвет этой линии при нажатии на кнопку. Могу заменить все свойство background, но ищу другой способ

Comment: Отформатировал вопрос и добавил идентификатор `layer_id` для айтема в layer list, для того чтобы можно было проще ответить на ваш вопрос. По идентификатору найти нужный layer проще.

Comment: На будущее: не указывайте тег `android-studio`, если вопрос не имеет никакого отношения к среде разработки, в которой вы разрабатываете.

Comment: В андроид студио создаю программу

Comment: Я если кто-то пишет код в блокноте, то теги будут microsoft, windows и блокнот? А если в vim, то linux, ubuntu и vim? Кому какая разница в каком редакторе (или ide) вы код пишете? Вопрос же не про ide, а про разработку под андроид. Извините, что на вас наезжаю, но почему-то многие не различают и ставят неправильный тег.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Я учту ваше замечание.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы программно поменять цвет для этого drawable, приведем его к `LayerDrawable`:

```kotlin
val layerDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.backborder) as LayerDrawable
```

Далее, найдем нужный layer по идентификатору и приведем его к `GradientDrawable`:

```kotlin
val gradientDrawable = layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.layer_id) as GradientDrawable
```

Этому gradient drawable можно задать цвет, это и будет solid цвет, который нам нужен:

```kotlin
gradientDrawable.setColor(Color.BLACK)
```

Теперь layer drawable изменен, можем его выставить как фон для `TextView`:

```kotlin
textView.background = layerDrawable
```

Comment: А если будет нужно заменить цвет не в  <solid, а в <stroke ?

Comment: В вопросе шла речь про solid color, поэтому я написал ответ про solid color. Чтобы поменять stroke: `gradientDrawable.setStroke(width, color)`.

Comment: Да, это уже по ходу вопрос появился. Но почему здесь setStroke, а когда речь шла о <solid , то не setSolid, а setColor ? Ведь Color встречается в нескольких местах

Comment: P.S. Аналогичный  код где то встречал, но там была работа по строкой кажется по её номеру в коде.

Comment: "Почему setColor, а не setSolid" -- так написали разработчики AOSP более 13 лет назад: [GradientDrawable.java](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.java)

Comment: а если нужно будет поменять что-то в `< item` или в `<shape` ?

Comment: Возникают артефакты, когда измененный фон переходит на другие поля